# php Random variable countdown limited in time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am writing a randomized countdown that show number of products left in promotion alongside a timer. Number of products left is stored in the database, so all users see the same number. I am using simple php/ajax/javascript solution. My problem is with distributing the random sales so all fit within limited timer and are nicely distributed.

Here is code I have so far:

```
function start() {
    $date= new DateTime();
    $prod_left = getval("SELECT * FROM counter LIMIT 1");
    if ( $prod_left == 20 ) {
        $fp = fopen("../index.html", "r+");
        while($buf = fgets($fp)){
            if(preg_match("/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/", $buf)){
                fputs($fp, '<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {$(".countdown").circularCountdown({startDate:"' . $date->format('Y/m/d H:i:s') . '",endDate:"' . $date->modify("+5minutes")->format('Y/m/d H:i:s') . '",timeZone:+2});});</script></body></html>');
            }
        }
        fclose($fp);
        sleep(30);
        while ($prod_left > 0) {
            if (rand(0,4) > 2) {
                $prod_left--;
                sleep(rand(1,13));
                updateval($prod_left);
            }
        }

    } else {
        echo 'Promocja w trakcie lub zakończona, zresetuj zegar, jeżeli chcesz rozpocząć ponownie';
    }
    exit;
}
```

My assumption here is: 50% of time decrease timer and wait on average 6.5 seconds, which should on average give me 260 seconds for full sale. Unfortunately its very unevenly distributed. **My goal is to have the $prod_value down to 0 not later than 270seconds after loop start, with quite evenly distributed value decreases (can accelerate towards ending)** Will you be able to help?

Implementation doesnt need to be in any particular programing language, im just looking for a clue/concept I can follow to achieve this.

What is the strangest, the $prod_left value not always goes to 0, on sime iterations it just sits at 3 or 5.

Please help!

Comment: Huh, are you actually writing javascript into a .html file based on some random time ?

Comment: Function start is called when I want to initiate countdown. I call it via ajax from control page, this way I initiate the clock countdown on index page.

Comment: instead of laughing you could provide constructive suggestions or help. @adeneo

Comment: I wasn't laughing, just asking, this seems like an utterly strange way to do things

Comment: @adeneo I am a beginer and didnt know how to do it easier. I have 2 pages, 1 'admin' with start and reset, 2 public.
When i click start on admin I want the timer to be initialized, so every user sees same time to end the promotion and same number of products left.